# How can I transition content off screen in one direction, fading it out, update the content and transition back in from the other side of the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-transitions

I have a div that has 2 buttons. If a button is pressed, I want to slide that div off screen to the left, fading out. Once off screen and hidden, update the content of the div, then move the div to the other side of the screen and slide if back in from the right.

I've tried to achieve this by detecting when a button is pressed, then updating the classes on the div to trigger a transition:

```
.exit-active {
    transform: translateX(-200%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform .5s ease-in,opacity .25s linear;
}
```

I then tried to use something like this to wait for this to finish before translating the div on the X axis by 400%:

```
$('.exit-active').on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd', function() { //do something });
```

And then in the do something bit, I'd update the content in the div, and then I was trying to remove my exit-active class, and update it with an entry-active class which would transition the div back into view from the right, fading back in.

I can get the first part working by sliding the div out to the left, fading out, and updating the content of the div, but I can't figure out how to shift the div whilst opacity is set to 0 over to the right of the screen and bring it back in with a similar effect. Any help would be appreciated.

One thing I have noted is that I can't seem to nest the js above inside a similar statement e.g. whilst waiting for a transition to complete, trigger another and wait for that one to complete too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could achieve this using `setTimeout`s and changing your ***classes*** within your *timeouts*. Just make sure the *timeouts* are set in a way that the intervals *accommodate the transition duration/s of your transforms*.

On the click, move the element off the screen, then run your first timeout. Within the timeout, change the ***class*** and `textContent` of your *event target*. The class will set `opacity` to `0` and move the element past the right fold of the screen. Then in the next timeout, set a new class, keeping the other class present so the ***transform*** will set when you bring it back to `translateX(0)`. We run two transitions, one for ***opacity*** and the other for ***transform***.

```js
const click = document.querySelectorAll('.click')

function moveEl(e){
  e.target.classList.add('move')
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.target.classList.remove('move')
    e.target.classList.add('right')
    e.target.textContent = 'I have been clicked!'
  }, 1000)
  setTimeout(()=>{
    e.target.classList.add('left')
  }, 2000)
}

click.forEach(clicks => {
    clicks.addEventListener('click', moveEl)
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.click {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
}

.move {
  transform: translateX(-400px);
  transition: transform .5s ease-in-out;
}

.right {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(100vw);
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: 
    transform .5s ease-in-out, 
    opacity .5s linear;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="click">Click me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Dale. Worked a treat. 